# Get multiple images width in JS

Tags: javascript

I am using a JS slider with 5 slides each with an image and a caption. I want to add a class only in that image where width > 2xheight. Following is my JS code:

```
$(".slides img").each(function() {

    var w = $("img.gallery").width();
    var h = $("img.gallery").height() * 2;

    if (w > h) {
        $(this).addClass("auto");
    };                    
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance,
Chirag.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div class="flex-container">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <span data-picture data-alt="WK Credentials">
                                <span data-src="images/large/slide1.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1601px)"></span>

                            </span>
                            <img src="images/slide5.jpg" id="myImg" alt="" title="" class="gallery" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <center>
                                <div class="intro">
                                    <h1 class="head">Incredible India | Tiffin</h1>
                                    <p class="text">Use what you know about your users to determine whether the words 
                                    and phrases you plan to use are appropriate.</p>
                                </div>
                            </center>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span data-picture data-alt="WK Credentials">
                                <span data-src="images/large/slide2.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1601px)"></span>

                            </span>
                            <img src="images/slide2.jpg" id="myImg" alt="" title="" class="gallery" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">This image is wrapped in a link!</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span data-picture data-alt="WK Credentials">
                                <span data-src="images/large/slide3.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1601px)"></span>

                            </span>
                            <img src="images/slide3.jpg" id="myImg" alt="" title="" class="gallery" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span data-picture data-alt="WK Credentials">
                                <span data-src="images/large/slide4.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1601px)"></span>

                            </span>
                            <img src="images/slide4.jpg" id="myImg" alt="" title="" class="gallery" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span data-picture data-alt="WK Credentials">
                                <span data-src="images/slide5.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1601px)"></span>
                            </span>
                            <img src="images/slide5.jpg" id="myImg" alt="" title="" class="gallery" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">Extra Wide Image</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
                    <li><a class="prev" href="#"><img src="images/themes.png" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                    <li><a class="next" href="#"><img src="images/themes.png" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".slides img").each(function(){
     $(this).load(function(){
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).height() *2;

        if(w > h){
          $(this).addClass("auto");
        };
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: @user3630952, see my comment on the other answer. If an image is not loaded into the DOM, it will return height and width 0.

Comment: @user3630952 Can you provide some additional information. If the above is not working, how is it failing? Is it selecting the wrong items, updating the wrong items, is it a syntax error? Perhaps a sample of your HTML markup would be useful as well so we can test locally before answering.

Comment: @user3630952 Here, am trying to bind load function for each image. And, once the image got loaded/already loaded then it will execute the code inside load it. So, the load function will execute only if/after the corresponding image is loaded. By the way, load() function supports all browsers including old IE browsers.

Comment: I want JS code for IE 9 and above. Lower version of IE browsers can be ignored.

Comment: Hi Guys, please be quick, i need its solution asap.

Comment: This should work. please check console for errors or inspect dom if class is added or not.

Comment: @user3630952 This will work in all browsers. Check it, it should works well perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the class "gallery" is actually significant here this might help, otherwise the other answers would work.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".slides img.gallery").each(function(){
        if($(this).width() > ($(this).height()*2)) {
            $(this).addClass("auto");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3630952 I have updated this and tested it locally with your code (although not your images as obviously they're not available). The biggest problem with the loading functions is that they are very flakey across browsers.

Comment: Further to the issue across browsers it's an issue known to jQuery developers: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Hi bejs, just try this code with 1 potrait image, 1 landscape image and 1 extra wide image.

Comment: I have tested this on Chrome and IE11 (and emulating IE9) and am not seeing any problem. It applies the auto class correctly.

Comment: Is it showing auto class on all images or on that image where condition is true?

Comment: Only the images where the width was at least twice the height got the "auto" class